# Подключение кастомной библиотеки в maven

Tags: java, maven

Сразу скажу - гуглил!

Мне нужно добавить библиотеку SimleCalc-1.0.jar.


 **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.homework</groupId>
    <artifactId>SimpleCalc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <systemPath>${basedir}\src\main\resources\SimpleCalc-1.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Если мои классы прамо в папке main/java/, то все работает.

 Но если классы моего приложения, например, в папке main/java/com.myapp/, то библиотека не подтягивается.

Пробовал через добавить библиотеку через

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file
```

Эффект тот же.

**Вопросы:**

Почему, если классы приложения не в папке main/java/ кастомная библиотека не подтягивается?

Как корректно добавлять кастомные библиотеки в maven?

Весь [pom.xml](https://github.com/andrey-gabchak/CalcSpringApp/blob/7098f9d493c9550eca0ac20625c419f7247954eb/pom.xml)

Answer (score 3):

Должно быть не `main/java/com.myapp/`, а main/java/com/myapp/ в соответствии со спецификацией языка. Для подключения библиотеки (jar-файла) достаточно, чтобы она была в `classpath`. Например, её можно добавить так:

```
java -jar -cp src/main/resources/SimpleCalc-1.0.jar %my_main_class%
```

Добавлять библиотеки через `systemPath` - моветон. Рекомендую *maven-dependency-plugin*, который добавит зависимости при сборке. Чтобы библиотеку было видно в IDE стоит сделать:

```
mvn install:install-file
```

Для этого можно подключить *maven-install-plugin*

Answer (score 0):

Если вы пытаетесь добавить в зависимость мавен-модулю свою библиотеку, которой нет в мавен репозитории (и добавлять ее туда точно не собираетесь), то можно создать свой локальный репозиторий, даже внутри проекта. Подложить туда свой `jar` файл и обозначить локальный репозиторий в `pom.xml`:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-maven-repository</id>
        <name>my-maven-repository</name>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/my-repository</url>
    </repository>
    <!-- Maven central repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

В папке с проектом (там где есть файл `pom.xml`) создаем папку с именем `my-repository`. Теперь только осталось правильно туда положить свой `jar`. В этом нам поможет [вот этот полезный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29261502/3955135)